# Not sure how to implement a reactive expression in my Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I'm fairly new to Shiny apps and I'm still not quite sure about how to implement reactive expressions in my app, despite reading a handful of tutorials how. Here is my attempt I doing so:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- navbarPage(title = h1("Analysis of Anime"),
             tabPanel("Genre",
                 titlePanel("Visualizing Genre"),
                 sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel(h4("Create plots of mean variables by genre."),
                                varSelectInput("var2", h5("Choose a variable to display."),
                                               data = anime %>% 
                                                 select(score, rank, popularity, members, favorites),
                                               selected = "popularity"),
                                sliderInput("toprange", h5("Display Top"),
                                            min = 5, max = 40, value = 5)),
                   mainPanel(plotOutput("bars"))
                   )
                 ), 
             tabPanel("Studio",
                  titlePanel("Visualizing Studios"),
                  sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel("Create histograms of variables by studio.",
                                varSelectInput("var", h5("Choose a variable to display."),
                                               data = anime %>% select(score, rank, popularity,
                                                                       members, favorites))),
                                mainPanel(plotOutput("hist"))

                 )
        ),
            tabPanel("Synopsis",
                     titlePanel("Synopsis Search & Text Mining"),
                     sidebarLayout(
                       sidebarPanel("Search for most relevant animes.",
                                    textInput("word", h5("Input a word to search for.")),
                                    actionButton("submit", "Search")
                     ),
                     mainPanel(tableOutput("search"))
                )
            )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  var2 <- reactive({input$var2})
  toprange <- reactive({input$toprange})
  var <- reactive({input$var})
  word <- reactive({input$word})

  output$bars <- renderPlot({
    genre_plot(var2(), toprange())
  })

  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    studio_plot(var())
  })

  output$search <- renderTable({
    word_freq(word())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here are the functions used:

```
library(tidyverse)
anime <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/
data/2019/2019-04-23/tidy_anime.csv")

genre_plot <- function(resp_variable, min) {
anime %>%
  group_by(genre) %>%
  drop_na(!!sym(resp_variable)) %>% 
  summarize(avg = mean(!!sym(resp_variable))) %>% 
  head(min) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(genre, avg), y = avg)) +
  geom_col(fill = "cornflowerblue", color = "black") +
  labs(x = "Genre", y = paste("Mean", resp_variable)) +
  ggtitle(paste("Mean", resp_variable, "by genre")) +
  coord_flip() 
}

studio_plot <- function(resp_variable) {
  anime %>% 
    group_by(studio) %>% 
    drop_na(!!sym(resp_variable)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = !!sym(resp_variable))) +
    geom_histogram(fill = "cornflowerblue") +
    labs(x = resp_variable, y = "Frequency") +
    ggtitle(paste("Frequency of", resp_variable))
}

word_freq <- function(word) {
  anime %>%
    distinct(name, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
    filter(str_detect(synopsis, word) | 
           str_detect(name, word)) %>% 
    select(name, synopsis)
}
```

When I implement this, the app runs fine but seems to still be rather slow and crash sometimes. Is there a better way to write this using reactive expressions?

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a reason to put variables into reactive expressions. You normally put your tables in reactive expressions so they can use the variables dynamically. Also fread from the data.table package should be way more efficient than read_csv. It would look something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

anime <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2019/2019-04-23/tidy_anime.csv")

ui <- navbarPage(title = h1("Analysis of Anime"),
                 tabPanel("Genre",
                          titlePanel("Visualizing Genre"),
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(h4("Create plots of mean variables by genre."),
                                         varSelectInput("var2", h5("Choose a variable to display."),
                                                        data = anime %>% 
                                                          select(score, rank, popularity, members, favorites),
                                                        selected = "popularity"),
                                         sliderInput("toprange", h5("Display Top"),
                                                     min = 5, max = 40, value = 5)),
                            mainPanel(plotOutput("bars"))
                          )
                 ), 
                 tabPanel("Studio",
                          titlePanel("Visualizing Studios"),
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel("Create histograms of variables by studio.",
                                         varSelectInput("var", h5("Choose a variable to display."),
                                                        data = anime %>% select(score, rank, popularity,
                                                                                members, favorites))),
                            mainPanel(plotOutput("hist"))

                          )
                 ),
                 tabPanel("Synopsis",
                          titlePanel("Synopsis Search & Text Mining"),
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel("Search for most relevant animes.",
                                         textInput("word", h5("Input a word to search for.")),
                                         actionButton("submit", "Search")
                            ),
                            mainPanel(tableOutput("search"))
                          )
                 )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  genre_plot <- reactive({
    anime %>%
      group_by(genre) %>%
      drop_na(!!sym(input$var2)) %>% 
      summarize(avg = mean(!!sym(input$var2))) %>% 
      head(input$toprange) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = reorder(genre, avg), y = avg)) +
      geom_col(fill = "cornflowerblue", color = "black") +
      labs(x = "Genre", y = paste("Mean", input$var2)) +
      ggtitle(paste("Mean", input$var2, "by genre")) +
      coord_flip() 
  })

  studio_plot <- reactive({
    anime %>% 
      group_by(studio) %>% 
      drop_na(!!sym(input$var)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = !!sym(input$var))) +
      geom_histogram(fill = "cornflowerblue") +
      labs(x = input$var, y = "Frequency") +
      ggtitle(paste("Frequency of", input$var))
  })

  word_freq <- reactive({
    anime %>%
      distinct(name, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
      filter(str_detect(synopsis, input$word) | 
               str_detect(name, input$word)) %>% 
      select(name, synopsis)
  })

  output$bars <- renderPlot({
    genre_plot()
  })

  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    studio_plot()
  })

  output$search <- renderTable({
    word_freq()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```